# Route all traffic that target to specific CIDR to an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Here are my resources on AWS:

```
EC2-01, IP = 10.0.1.1, disable src/dest check, in VPC-01, CIDR = 10.0.1.0/24  
EC2-02, IP = 10.0.2.1, in VPC-02, CIDR = 10.0.2.0/24
```

I want all traffic that target to 10.0.1.0/24 can be routed to 10.0.0.1.
So I use these route rule:

```
VPC-01:  
10.0.1.0/24 -> local  
0.0.0.0/0   -> 10.0.1.1

VPC-02:  
10.0.2.0/24 -> local
10.0.1.0/24 -> VPC-01
```

If I ping 10.0.1.5 from EC2-02, I can not receive ping in EC2-01

**It's wired, and I did another experiment**

```
VPC-01:  
10.0.1.0/24 -> local  
0.0.0.0/0   -> 10.0.1.1  
192.168.0.0/24 -> 10.0.1.1 // new rule

VPC-02:
10.0.2.0/24 -> local
10.0.1.0/24 -> VPC-01  
192.168.0.0/24 -> VPC-01 // new rule
```

If I ping 192.168.0.5 from EC2-02, I can receive ping in EC2-01.

Doest anyone know why I can not ping 10.0.1.5 ?

Comment: Please note that using PING to test network connectivity is not necessarily a good idea. Ping requires Allow rules for ICMP in the Security Groups. Therefore, when you are using PING to test connectivity, you are merely testing whether PING works -- it won't tell you whether other connectivity works. Instead, it is better to test the _actual_ connectivity you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you wish to route all traffic for `10.0.1.0/24` to `10.0.0.1`. In fact, what is located at `10.0.0.1`? Is it a Peered VPC? Please note that this will impact all traffic _within_ the `10.0.1.0/24` subnet. You might also be interested in: [Amazon VPC Routing Enhancements Allow You to Inspect Traffic Between Subnets In a VPC | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/inspect-subnet-to-subnet-traffic-with-amazon-vpc-more-specific-routing/)

Comment: there is a WireGuard server hosted in 10.0.1.1, I want to receive traffic and forward them to my on-premise site through WireGuard